# How do I change state asynchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get the coords of the user and once done I'm trying to use "useState" to make that position global but for some reason it's always returning undefined the first time it's ran even though I'm using a promise.

```
    const [globalPosition, setGlobalPosition] = useState<any>(undefined);

useEffect(() => {
    const getLocation = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
        });
        function success(position: any) {
            setGlobalPosition(position);
            resolve();
        }
        function error(err: any) {
            console.log(err);
            reject();
        }
    });
    getLocation.then(() => {
        console.log(globalPosition);
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: I would suggest reading up on how callbacks work and how to [use Promises properly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). The way you have it written, your success and error functions will not get called.

Comment: @MForMarlon OP uses `success` and `error` as callbacks to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`, they just did it in the less readable (imo) way of using them before defining them (which is valid do to hoisting)

Comment: yeah I think i'll spend some times on those, I still feel like I haven't learned them properly, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first render will always be `undefined` because that's what you defined as the initial value.

```js
const [globalPosition, setGlobalPosition] = useState<any>(undefined);
//                                                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

When a state setting function is called, such as inside your `useEffect`, the component will rerender.

If you don't want to continue rendering while  `undefined`, *after* that `useEffect` add one of these options (or your own loading state):

```js
if (globalPosition == undefined) return null;
```

```js
if (globalPosition == undefined) return <div>Loading...</div>;
```

Also because of how React state and `const` work, `getLocation.then`'s `globalPosition` will *not* be the new version of the variable after you change it since it's storing a copy/reference to the original state at the beginning of that render.

Comment: I just want to render the location initially, or more precisely get the latitude and longitude from them and use it in another component